# How can I structured Js Object

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to convert this Object

```
var users = {
    'c9b17cd29025fae1189168f55bd13f4e' : { 
       name: 'abc', amountMsg: 11 
     },

    '02d3c5737ac8861a6e80cf50322745e2':  { 
       name: 'def', amountMsg: 8 
    },
  
     '312wewq213a6e80hj43l42lmn6m7n3m':  { 
       name: 'ghj', amountMsg: 4 
    }
};
```

to like this

```
var users = [
       {
         id : 'c9b17cd29025fae1189168f55bd13f4e', 
         name: 'abc', 
         amountMsg: 11 
       },

       {
         id : '02d3c5737ac8861a6e80cf50322745e2', 
         name: 'def', 
         amountMsg: 8 
       },

       {
         id : '312wewq213a6e80hj43l42lmn6m7n3m', 
         name: 'ghj', 
         amountMsg: 4 
       }
];
```

this users return my server.js I would like to convert it to second one to access values easy

thanks

Comment: The second one is not valid JavaScript. An object must have keys. Do you want an array instead?

Comment: yeap sorry, I wrote wrong . it should be [ ] instead of { }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want an array in the second example.

```js
var users = {
    'c9b17cd29025fae1189168f55bd13f4e' : { 
       name: 'abc', amountMsg: 11 
     },

    '02d3c5737ac8861a6e80cf50322745e2':  { 
       name: 'def', amountMsg: 8 
    },
  
     '312wewq213a6e80hj43l42lmn6m7n3m':  { 
       name: 'ghj', amountMsg: 4 
    }
};

let formattedUsers = Object.entries(users).map(([id, data]) => ({id: id, ...data}));
console.log(formattedUsers);
```

Comment: you can minify it a little if you use `({id, ...data})` instead of `({id: id, ...data})`

Answer (score 0):

Objects must have keys. However, if you want to transform your set of objects to an array - you can do next:

```js
var users = {
    'c9b17cd29025fae1189168f55bd13f4e' : { 
       name: 'abc', amountMsg: 11 
     },

    '02d3c5737ac8861a6e80cf50322745e2':  { 
       name: 'def', amountMsg: 8 
    },
  
     '312wewq213a6e80hj43l42lmn6m7n3m':  { 
       name: 'ghj', amountMsg: 4 
    }
};

var modified = Object.keys(users).map(key => ({
  ...users[key],
  id: key,
}));

console.log(modified);
```

Comment: Using `Object.entries` is more elegant and (more importantly) less error prone (considere renaming `users`, you need to change it also inside the map, which is not the case for `.entries`)